# Create json object from tree structure in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, recursion, nested

I have a nested tree data structure of *groups* and *layers* that need to be generated from a couple of joined database tables and then be stored as JSON in a PostgreSQL (version 12.8) database. Groups can contain layer objects, but also (sub)groups. The desired JSON output (generated via SQL and/or function) would look like shown below.

```
    [{
    "title": "Folder 1",
    "type": "group",
    "folded": false,
    "layers": [{
            "title": "Layer 1",
            "type": "WMS",
            "visible": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Folder 2",
            "type": "group",
            "folded": true,
            "layers": [{
                    "title": "Layer 2",
                    "type": "WMS",
                    "visible": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "Layer 3",
                    "type": "WMS",
                    "visible": true
                },
                {
                    "title": "Folder 3",
                    "type": "group",
                    "folded": true,
                    "layers": [{
                            "title": "Layer 4",
                            "type": "WMS",
                            "visible": false
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Layer 5",
                            "type": "WMS",
                            "visible": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

These are the database tables and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jtest.folders
(
id serial,
item_id integer,
title text,
folded boolean NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jtest.layers
(
id serial,
item_id integer,
title text,
type text, 
visible boolean
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jtest."connect"
(
    id serial,
    item_id integer,
    child_id integer,
    layer boolean DEFAULT true
);

--data
INSERT INTO jtest.folders(id, item_id, title, folded) VALUES 
(1,1,'Folder 1',false),(2,2,'Folder 2', true),(3,3,'Folder 3', true); 

INSERT INTO jtest.layers(item_id,id,title,type,visible) VALUES
(1,4,'Layer 1','WMS',true),(2,5,'Layer 2','WMS',true),(3,6,'Layer 3','WMS',true),(4,7,'Layer 4','WMS',true),(5,8,'Layer 5','WMS',true);

INSERT INTO jtest.connect (item_id, child_id, layer) VALUES
(1,4,true),(1,2,false),(2,5,true),(2,6,true),(2,3,false),(3,7,true),(3,8,true);
```

I partially succeeded to generate a JSON output for a simple folder-layer tree using queries like the one below, but could not figure out how to correctly handle folders nested into a list of layers (aka sub folders).

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(sub)
from (
    SELECT f.id, f.folded,f.item_id,f.title, to_jsonb(array_agg(l.*)) as layers 
  FROM jtest.folders f
          JOIN   jtest.connect c ON f.item_id = c.item_id
          JOIN   jtest.layers l ON  l.item_id = c.child_id 
  where c.layer is true
    GROUP  BY f.id,f.folded,f.item_id,f.title
    ORDER  BY f.item_id ) sub;
```

Any ideas or examples on how to solve this ?

Comment: You'll need a recursive CTE

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your `connect` table. Does that mean a child element can be connected to multiple parents? Or is that a `unique` column? And what's the `layer boolean`, does that encode whether the `child_id` refers to the folders or layers table? Also I wonder why all of your objects have both an `id` and an `item_id`, what's the difference?

Comment: @Bergi  A child object can have only one parent. The `id` columns are the primary key, `item_id` is used to join parents with child objects. `layer` boolean indicates if it is a folder or layer object